# Is it possible to change plugin's Admin Panel Url?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I'm curious to know can I change the admin panel URL from `mydomain.com/wp-admin/?page=my-plugin` to `mydomain.com/wp-admin/my-plugin.php`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generaly no, or at least if you work hard enough to make it happen it will make much more sense to just use `mydomain.com/wp-admin/my-plugin` (without the php extension).

The reason is that by default the htaccess rules wordpress uses, first try to locate a file in the implied path, and if it is not there it "fires" the front end processing, something you most likely do not want to happen in the context of admin session. Therefor urls under `wp-admin` should map to actual PHP files at the implied location.

How to get around this limitation? There are two parts with the easiest one is modifying the htaccess to map the url you want for your admin page into the "normal" wordpress admin url, or intercept the URL very early in the processing of the request and modify the relevant PHP globals appropriately. The harder one will be to modify the output of the relevant admin APIs to generate the right URL in the relevant contexts and there might be always some additional unexpected edge cases that you will need to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I accept this as a correct answer since there is all the information I need to know about

Answer (score -1):

As per your questions, I think  you want to call separate php file (my-plugin.php) on plugin menu click. If i am right you can follow code below otherwise sorry for that.

you can call this through callback function.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page(
          'My Plugin Options'
        , 'My Plugin'
        , 'manage_options'
        , 'my-unique-identifier'
        , 'my_plugin_options'
    );
}

function my_plugin_options() {
    require 'my-plugin.php';
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this already for loading my plugin specific settings on the admin panel. But the question is how I could change the admin panel URL from ?page= to my-plugin.php